# How to add total of column together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiplied TJM.intMaterialQuantity * TM.monMaterialCost That gives me the total of each material item in separate rows.  I need those 4 totals added up and placed into a new column called monTotalMaterialCost.  The way it is now shows each material in monTotalMaterialCost.  How do I get the total of all materials into one row so I can see the job and customer and total cost in one row?

```
SELECT
     TJ.intJobID
    ,TC.intCustomerID
    ,TC.strLastName + ', ' + TC.strFirstName AS strCustomerName
    ,(SUM (TJM.intMaterialQuantity) * SUM (TM.monMaterialCost)) AS monTotalMaterialCost


FROM
     TJobs              AS TJ 
    ,TJobCustomers      AS TJC
    ,TCustomers         AS TC 
    ,TJobMaterials      AS TJM
    ,TMaterials         AS TM 

WHERE
        TJ.intJobID         =   TJC.intJobID
    AND TJC.intCustomerID   =   TC.intCustomerID
    AND TJM.intMaterialID   =   TM.intMaterialID
    AND TJM.intJobID        =   TJ.intJobID
    AND TJ.intJobID          = 1

GROUP BY
     TJ.intJobID
    ,TC.intCustomerID
    ,TC.strLastName + ', ' + TC.strFirstName 
    ,TJM.intMaterialQuantity
    ,TM.monMaterialCost
```

SAMPLE INPUT

```
--Insert into TMaterials
INSERT INTO TMaterials ( intMaterialID, strMaterials, monMaterialCost )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Nails', '4.99' )

INSERT INTO TMaterials ( intMaterialID, strMaterials, monMaterialCost )
VALUES  ( 2, 'Drywall per 32 sqft', '12.99' )

INSERT INTO TMaterials ( intMaterialID, strMaterials, monMaterialCost )
VALUES  ( 3, '2 x 4', '1.89' )

INSERT INTO TMaterials ( intMaterialID, strMaterials, monMaterialCost )
VALUES  ( 4, 'Paint per gallon', '32.00' )

INSERT INTO TMaterials ( intMaterialID, strMaterials, monMaterialCost )
VALUES  ( 5, 'Tile per sqft', '4.99' )

INSERT INTO TMaterials ( intMaterialID, strMaterials, monMaterialCost )
VALUES  ( 6, 'Copper Water 10ft line', '6.99' )

INSERT INTO TMaterials ( intMaterialID, strMaterials, monMaterialCost )
VALUES  ( 7, 'Screws', '4.99' )

INSERT INTO TMaterials ( intMaterialID, strMaterials, monMaterialCost )
VALUES  ( 8, 'Shingles', '40.99' )

INSERT INTO TMaterials ( intMaterialID, strMaterials, monMaterialCost )
VALUES  ( 9, 'Tar Paper per sqft', '1.99' )

 --Insert into TJobMaterials

 --Materials for Job 1 Customer 1
 INSERT INTO TJobMaterials ( intJobID, intMaterialID, intMaterialQuantity )
 VALUES (1, 1, 50 )

 INSERT INTO TJobMaterials ( intJobID, intMaterialID, intMaterialQuantity )
 VALUES (1, 2, 20 )

 INSERT INTO TJobMaterials ( intJobID, intMaterialID, intMaterialQuantity )
  VALUES    (1, 3, 20 )

 INSERT INTO TJobMaterials ( intJobID, intMaterialID, intMaterialQuantity )
 VALUES (1, 4, 5 )

 INSERT INTO TJobMaterials ( intJobID, intMaterialID, intMaterialQuantity )
 VALUES (1, 5, 35 )

 /*
Output I'm Getting

intJobID    strJobDescription    intJobStatusID    strJobStatus    monTotalMaterialCost
   1          Kitchen Remodel           3            Complete           160.00
   1          Kitchen Remodel           3            Complete           37.80
   1          Kitchen Remodel           3            Complete           259.80
   1          Kitchen Remodel           3            Complete           174.65
   1          Kitchen Remodel           3            Complete           249.50

   Output Wanted

   intJobID    strJobDescription    intJobStatusID    strJobStatus    monTotalMaterialCost
      1         Kitchen Remodel          3              Complete            881.75

      I need the total of all 5 outputs into one final total into monTotalMaterialCost
```

*/

The needed output:
    intJobID  = 1     strJobDescription = Kitchen Remodel    strJobStatus = Complete       monTotalMaterialCost =  881.75

What I'm Getting:
    intJobID = 1       strJobDescription =  Kitchen Remodel       strJobStatus = Complete       monTotalMaterialCost =   7391.80

What is happening:  I have 5 different Materials from TJM.intMaterialQuantity.  Each value from each row is 50, 20, 20, 5, 35 Then I have 5 different Cost for each material from TM.monMaterialCost those values matching in same order 4.99,12.99, 1.89, 32.00, 4.99.  I am getting the 50+20+20+5+35 = 130 and 4.99+12.99+1.89+32.00+4.99 = 56.86 So I am getting in the final equation 130 * 56.86 = 7,391.80.

What I need is 50 * 4.99 = 249.50, 20 * 12.99 = 259.80, 20 * 1.89 = 37.80, 5 * 32.00 = 160, 35 * 4.99 = 174.65 The I need to add all of those totals together for a total amount spent on materials for the job for a total of 881.75.

I hope this helps better understand my question.

I have figured it out. I have posted correct answer for future questions:

```
SELECT
 TJ.intJobID
,TJ.strJobDescription
,TJ.intJobStatusID
,TJS.strJobStatus
, SUM (TJM.intMaterialQuantity * TM.monMaterialCost) AS monTotalMaterialCost


FROM TJobs AS TJ    
        join TJobMaterials AS TJM on TJM.intJobID = TJ.intJobID
        join TMaterials AS TM on TJM.intMaterialID = TM.intMaterialID
        join TJobStatus AS TJS on TJ.intJobStatusID = TJS.intJobStatusID

GROUP BY
 TJ.intJobID
,TJ.strJobDescription
,TJ.intJobStatusID
,TJS.strJobStatus
```

Comment: If you can give a sample input and a sample output it would be easier to help you

Comment: Just delete columns TJM.intMaterialQuantity, TM.monMaterialCost from GROUP BY clause

Comment: @IgorBorisenko that doesn't work.  I get 73910.80.  The total should be 3,138.75

Comment: @TonyDong I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @gh9 I have added the inputs for the materials and the materials used in job 1.

Comment: @BradWethington I see the input, but I do not see any output

Comment: @gh9 Let me know if that helps.  I can post a screen shot if that will help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You really should stop using the antiquated ANSI-89 style joins. The ANSI-92 style joins have been around for 25 years now. They are much simpler to read and prevents a lot of accidental mistakes.

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

The second half of your query would look like this.

```
FROM TJobs AS TJ 
join TJobCustomers AS TJC on TJ.intJobID = TJC.intJobID
join TCustomers AS TC on TJC.intCustomerID = TC.intCustomerID
join TJobMaterials AS TJM on TJM.intJobID = TJ.intJobID
join TMaterials AS TM on TJM.intMaterialID = TM.intMaterialID
WHERE TJ.intJobID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise! I'm still learning. This gives me each materials total in each row.  This gives me 5 rows.  I need the total of all 5 rows into one column in one row.  For example, This query gives me 37.80, 174.65, 249.50, 259.80, 160.00 These are the totals for each different material multiplied by their quantity.  I then need to add all of those together so I show the one row giving the total of all materials for the job.